# Take and use input as number

Tags: shell

```
grep -o '\w\{4\}' file
```

I want to find the words longer than a value given by the user. Now, the above code gives me the words with at least 4 letters but if I'm replacing 4 with `$n` after i read a number into n it says that the content between my brackets is incorrect. How could I use a value read instead of a predefined one?

Comment: Use double quotes.  Single quotes would prevent variable expansion.

Comment: Why is it closed as unclear when people were able to give an answer without asking for details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single quotes, the `$n` will not be interpreted. It works if you use double quotes:

```
grep -o "\w\{$n\}" file
```

But I think you will want to use

```
grep -o "\w\{$n,\}" file
```

because else words of length 8-11 will match twice, 12-15 three times etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
n=5
eval "grep -o '\w\{$n\}'  filename"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Providing additional explanatory text always improves an answer.